# Impute missing columns of a pandas dataframe based on values in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm practising some data cleaning on the titanic dataset from Kaggle. What I'm currently trying to do is impute missing age values. Instead of trying to impute using the generic median of the age column, I'm instead trying to be more specific by imputing missing ages based on the median of the age column for rows that share the same title.

I've tried the following (which throws up a 'SettingWithCopyWarning' message):

```
# import data
train_df = pd.read_csv('Data/train.csv', header=0)

# create title field
train_df['Title'] = train_df['Name'].str.extract(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.', expand=False)

# create boolean of rare titles
rare_titles = (train_df['Title'].value_counts() < 10)

# replace rare title values
df['Title'] = df['Title'].replace({x: 'Rare' for x in rare_titles[rare_titles].index})

# impute missing age values based on title
# ignore the for loop indent error, can't format it correctly on stackoverflow for some reason
title_list = df.Title.unique()
for title in title_list:
train_df.loc[train_df['Title']==title].Age.fillna(train_df.loc[train_df['Title']==title].Age.median(), inplace=True)
```

Is there a better way of doing this? The code I've used throws up a warning message and it's also quite messy to read/write/look at, so I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution out there somewhere!